# Are exaggerated bad reviews subject to nezikin

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, business, lashon-hara-slander, torts-damages

According to Halacha, if somebody speaks negatively about a product or device  in an exaggerated manner (that would constitute Lashon harah) is that subject to Nezikin and actionable in a Beit Din? In this case, the business in question loses customers due to the negative speech.

Comment: Its a big grama. Which one cant charge for. The only question is bidei shamayim would he be obligated, but it seems too indirect to obligate even that.

Comment: I don't think one could owe money for Lashon Hara, as bad as it is.

Comment: https://www.jewishpress.com/judaism/halacha-hashkafa/does-halacha-have-libel-laws/2020/06/10/

Comment: Part 2: https://www.jewishpress.com/judaism/halacha-hashkafa/does-halacha-have-libel-laws-part-ii/2020/06/19/

Comment: https://www.psakim.org/Psakim/File/2562 המפסיד פרנסתו של חבירו - באופן שלא התירו חז"ל - הוא גזלן מהתורה, וחייב לסלק את הנזק. אבל אין חייב מעיקר הדין לתקן העולה שעשה. ומכל מקום, ראוי שבית דין יקנוס אותו על העוולה שעשה. וכלפי שמים חייב לתקן את העולה שעשה, וראוי לשלם מה שהפסידו.